# Spring Social .NET OAuth confusion

Tags: spring, sharepoint-2010, twitter, twitter-oauth, spring.net

I had originally posted a question about what API to use in regards to making a SharePoint 2010 timer job able to access the twitter API and chose the Spring Social .NET api and have run into another roadblock.

I cannot get the OAuth handshake or 'dance' to work.

I have the consumer key and secret linked to my account, as well as an access token and secret, but any time I try to initialize a TwitterServiceProvider object, any time I attempt to query I get a 401 error.

The console/mvc and wp7.1 examples provided dont give much insight how I can get this code (which should run with no human involvement) to work.

Does anyone have any good resources regarding this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have access token value and secret, you can do something like that:

```
ITwitter twitter = new TwitterTemplate("consumerKey", "consumerSecret", "accessTokenValue", "accessTokenSecret");
// twitterApi.UserOperations.GetUserProfile();
```

that is equivalent to :

```
TwitterServiceProvider serviceProvider = new TwitterServiceProvider("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
ITwitter twitterApi = serviceProvider.GetApi("accessTokenValue", "accessTokenSecret");
// twitterApi.UserOperations.GetUserProfile();
```

How do you get the access token secret and value?

Comment: I am getting this error from Visual Studio when I try to debug..The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Oh, and I got the access token and secret from dev.twitter.com

Comment: It is possible that the SSL/TLS connection issue is due to a blockage between my server and the internet as I do not manage them. I will try this method in a console app at home, and if that works I have to wait until the server team removes the restrictions.

Comment: Im going to accept this answer as I tried at home and it worked. I will forward this issue to the people who manage the server and get them to fix it. Thanks!